# disable text selection of HTML element

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using the jQuery UI function `.disableSelection()` to disable text selection. While it works fine for `<div>` elements, I can't get it to work for `<input>` elements. Any suggestions?

Here is an example of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/7SfBx/

Comment: Works for me on Firefox 5 on my Mac...

Comment: You're right, it works with Firefox! But I'm working with Chrome.

Comment: works fine in IE 8 as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are looking to stop text selecting rather than disable an element, you can modify your code slightly to achieve this. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/7SfBx/2/

```
$('.test').disableSelection().css('webkit-user-select','none');
```

Answer (score 0):

$(".test").attr("disabled", true);

Comment: Disabling is not the same as no text selection.